# Passing Parameters to DLT task in Databricks workflows

Tags: python, databricks, delta-live-tables

I am making use of Databricks Workflows. I have a job that consists of three tasks:

1. Extract - references a normal databricks notebook
2. DLT - references a dlt pipeline
3. PostExec - references a normal databricks notebook

I pass a parameter into the first task making use of the parameters options.  In the notebook, I register the parameter with the following code, so that I can reference it later in the following tasks:
dbutils.jobs.taskValues.set("parmater_1", parameter_value)

I can then reference this parameter in the tasks that also reference notebooks with the following code:
parameter_1 = dbutils.jobs.taskValues.get(taskKey="Extract",key="parmater_1")

But I cannot reference this value in the tasks that refer to DLT pipelines.  When I run the above code, it produces the following error:
**TypeError: Must pass debugValue when calling get outside of a job context. debugValue cannot be None.**

I know DLT uses configuration, but is it possible to persist a parameter in the first step to be passed programmatically to the DLT step?

Answer (score 0):

Task values aren't supported for DLT yet... You can pass only the configuration parameters defined in the pipeline's settings or Spark conf.

Comment: any update on support for Task Values for DLT... would be very useful if its supported in DLT